# Child div with fixed position must be inside parent div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working with some editor plugin. When editor render code information with position fixed than it display out of the editor div. It should be render with in parent div.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="width: 50%; border:1px solid black; overflow: hidden;">
parent
<table style="width: 100%; margin:0px 0px 5px 0px; top: 93px; position:fixed; left: 0;display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 44px; background-color: #ffbf1e; z-index: 998;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 191, 30);">
                child
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fixed positions an element to the viewport, not it's parent element. If you don't want this behavior, don't position it fixed.

Comment: actually it is code editor. user what where want to write code with in it and when user used fixed position than it start problem.

Comment: @Gad child should be display with in parent div.

Comment: If I understand you you're allowing users to write markup into an editor and they are positioning things fixed. Is this correct? If it is then you need to filter their input to remove the ability for them to do that or render their input into an iframe. Ultimately, allowing users to write executable content is extremely dangerous. It opens you up to all sorts of xss attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, the CSS specification requires that `position:fixed` be anchored to the viewport, not the containing positioned element. For you, that means that you can not solve it purely by CSS.

- Use javascript to manually remove/replace all fixed positions from all elements.
- Use `<iframe>` instead of div. It has its own viewport and therefore the fixed position will be relative to parent iframe borders.

Answer (score 0):

when an element which have its parent has position which is `fixed` or `absolute` while its parent doesn't have position defined the child on follow the measurement of the `body`
tag for example when you defined two `div` parent and child but not set the position to both the child will follow measurement of its parent in the following example i set parent `width` to `50%` of `body` and child to `100%` of its parent

```css
.parent {
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

but when I set the position of child to fixed or absolute and set its width to `100%` the width won't depend on its parent it depend on the `body`

```css
.parent {
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

that's why a child with `fixed` or `absolute` position can't depend on its parent except when you set the parent's position to `relative` but won't behave the same like you din't define position